# C - Valgrind Conditional Jump errors

Tags: c, string, pointers, valgrind

I'm a newcomer to C, and I've been tasked with recreating the string.h standard library (or at least the most popular commands). We have been given a "tester" program to check our work automatically, and have the extra requirement that our code compiles with the switches-std=c99 and -Wall in addition to being error free when run through valgrind.

Although my code works and there are no compilation issues, valgrind is giving me several errors, all of which are `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`.

My understanding of this error is that somewhere I am using a variable that has yet to be initialized to a value. No matter how I hard I look, I fail to find a variable that is not initialized. I'm thinking at this point that my issue may have something to do with pointers, but I'm not at a level of understanding in terms of C to find the issue with my code.

Below is my work.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t my_strlen(const char* s){    
        size_t count = 0;    
        while(*s != '\0'){
                count++;
                s++;
        }    
        return count;
}

char* my_strcpy(char* tgt, const char* src){    
        while(*src != '\0'){
                *tgt = *src;
                tgt++;
                src++;
        }    
        return tgt;    
}

int my_strcmp(const char* s1, const char* s2){
        while(*s1 != '\0'){
                if(*s1 != *s2){
                        if(*s2 == '\0'){
                                return 1;
                        }
                        else if(*s1 > *s2){
                                return 1;
                        }
                        else{
                                return -1;
                        }
                }

                s1++; s2++;
        }

        if(*s2 != '\0'){
                return -1;
        }    
        return 0;

}

char* my_strcat(char* tgt, const char* src){    
        while(*tgt != '\0'){
                tgt++;
        }

        while(*src != '\0'){
                *tgt = *src;
                src++;
                tgt++;
        }    
        return tgt;
}

char* my_strchr(const char *s,  int c){    
        while(*s != '\0'){
                if(*s == (char) c){
                        return (char*) s;
                }
                s++;
        }

        return NULL;    
}
char* my_strrchr(const char *s,  int c){

        char* last = NULL;
        while(*s != '\0'){

                if(*s == (char) c){
                        last = (char*) s;
                }
                s++;

        }

        return last;

}
```

Here is the tester (not written by myself):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "project.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int SIGN(int x) {
  if(x < 0) { return -1; }
  if(x > 0) { return +1; }
  return 0;
}

/* Gold testing: compare the results of your functions to the results
   of functions known correct for the same computational problem. */

int main() {
  int i, j;
  int M = 200;

  char* s1 = malloc((M+1) * sizeof(char));
  char* s2 = malloc((M+1) * sizeof(char));
  char* s3 = malloc((M+1) * sizeof(char));

  printf("Starting out the CPS 393 project test program.\n");

  for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    s1[i] = 'a' + (rand() % 26);
  }
  s1[i] = '\0';
  assert(strlen(s1) == my_strlen(s1));

  printf("Passed stage one. Current score: 3\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for(j = i; j < M; j++) {
      my_strcpy(s2, s1 + j);
      strcpy(s3, s1 + j);
      assert(SIGN(strcmp(s2, s3)) == SIGN(my_strcmp(s2, s3)));
   }
  }

  printf("Passed stage two. Current score: 8\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    assert(strlen(s1 + i) == my_strlen(s1 + i));
    for(j = 0; j < M; j++) {
      assert(SIGN(strcmp(s1 + i, s1 + j)) == SIGN(my_strcmp(s1 + i, s1 + j)));
    }
  }

  printf("Passed stage three. Current score: 12\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for(j = 'a'; j <= 'z'; j++) {
      assert(strchr(s1 + i, j) == my_strchr(s1 + i, j));
      assert(strrchr(s1 + i, j) == my_strrchr(s1 + i, j));
    }
  }
  free(s2);
  free(s3);

  printf("Passed stage four. Current score: 16\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  s2 = malloc(M*M*sizeof(char));
  s3 = malloc(M*M*sizeof(char));
  s2[0] = '\0';
  s3[0] = '\0';
  for(i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    strcat(s2, s1 + i);
    my_strcat(s3, s1 + i);
  }
  assert(strcmp(s2, s3) == 0);

  printf("Passed stage five. Current score: 20\n");
  fflush(stdout);

  free(s1);
  free(s2);
  free(s3);
  printf("Test program for 393 project completed.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Here is what valgrind is giving me (I've included --track-origins=yes as I've read that it helps find the problem. Hasn't helped me though!):

```
==16780== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16780== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16780== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16780== Command: ./project
==16780==
Starting out the CPS 393 project test program.
Passed stage one. Current score: 3
==16780== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16780==    at 0x40256E3: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:426)
==16780==    by 0x8048919: main (in 393/project)
==16780==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==16780==    at 0x4023F50: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==16780==    by 0x80487E0: main (in 393/project)
==16780==
==16780== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16780==    at 0x40256D5: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:426)
==16780==    by 0x8048919: main (in 393/project)
==16780==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==16780==    at 0x4023F50: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==16780==    by 0x80487E0: main (in 393/project)
==16780==
==16780== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16780==    at 0x80486D5: my_strcmp (in 393/project)
==16780==    by 0x8048937: main (in 393/project)
==16780==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==16780==    at 0x4023F50: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==16780==    by 0x80487E0: main (in 393/project)
==16780==
Passed stage two. Current score: 8
Passed stage three. Current score: 12
Passed stage four. Current score: 16
==16780== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16780==    at 0x8048700: my_strcat (in 393/project)
==16780==    by 0x8048C53: main (in 393/project)
==16780==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==16780==    at 0x4023F50: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==16780==    by 0x8048C04: main (in 393/project)
==16780==
==16780== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16780==    at 0x40256E3: strcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:426)
==16780==    by 0x8048C76: main (in 393/project)
==16780==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==16780==    at 0x4023F50: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==16780==    by 0x8048C04: main (in 393/project)
==16780==
Passed stage five. Current score: 20
Test program for 393 project completed.
==16780==
==16780== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16780==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16780==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 80,603 bytes allocated
==16780==
==16780== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16780==
==16780== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==16780== ERROR SUMMARY: 203 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)
```

Comment: Fyi, your `my_strcpy` doesn't terminate `tgt` properly. Trivial example, consider the case where an empty string `""` is passed as the source. `my_strcat` suffers a similar fate.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the heads up. I'd assume that all I'd have to do is add on '\0' to the end of tgt? But that still doesn't solve my valgrind errors.

Comment: Your `my_strcat()` also fails to terminate the target string.  This failure and the one in `my_strcpy()` would explain the Valgrind errors, and I don't see anything else that would.  Only your functions that (are supposed to) modify strings are even candidates.  (The error is not detected until later, when a string that one of your functions has modified is examined.)

Comment: Many thanks for the info. This seems to have solved all my issues. I'm used to Java where I get told what my errors are simply. Valgrind likes to be much more cryptic.